# How to find all properties and methods available for a given type?

Tags: swift, documentation

I'm reading through The Swift Programming Language for Swift 2.2, and I've come across some code that calls the enumerate() method on an array.  I wanted to know more about this method, so I looked it up in Swift Standard Library Reference, but there's no mention of this method on Array's page (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Array_Structure/).  I thought I'd check for any superclasses that might implement it, but Array doesn't inherit from anything.

I searched a bit, and found that the enumerate() method is part of the  SequenceType protocol, and then I eventually realised that Array conforms to the CollectionType protocol which inherits from SequenceType so Array has to implement enumerate().

My question is this: is there an easier way to establish exactly what properties and methods are available for a given type?  Right now I can only think of using Xcode's code completion and scanning through the available options, but it seems to me there must be a better way?

Comment: This kind of poor documentation is such a time waster.  I would consider this a bug in the docs, and suggest giving them some direct feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest using swiftdoc.org. It handles the concept of protocols and inheritance while showing the [relation](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/type/Array/hierarchy/) between the both of them.

For instance, it shows that very [method](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/type/Array/#func-enumerate) on [Array](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/type/Array/).